# masses of wounded or the wounded

Tags: word-usage

> The warning came as hospitals in Gaza struggled to treat masses of **wounded** with dwindling resources, and health officials in the Hamas-ruled territory said the death toll was soaring as Israeli jets continued striking the territory overnight into Wednesday.[From APnews](https://apnews.com/article/israel-palestinians-war-gaza-hamas-94db5fa6029977f302cf2af57349badc)

I've learned [the wounded](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wounded) means people who are injured. I wonder why there is no "the" but an adjective following a preposition in the sentence.

Comment: In the cited context, it's *almost* entirely arbitrary whether to include the article or not. But note that we're more likely to refer to ***the** wounded* in contexts where we might *expect* a lot of wounded people - which is normally, *wounded **soldiers*** in the context of a full-blown war between nation-states. So at least *some* writers might balk at including ***the*** here because it *very slightly* elevates the "status" of the conflict between Israel and Hamas by implying that Hamas are credible representatives of a nation state, capable of engaging in a (relatively) civilized "war".

Answer (score -1):

It follows other patterns in English:  swarms of bees, flocks of birds, or masses of wounded (as in wounded people).

Comment: Bees and birds aren't closely comparable to wounded. Look at "village of the damned", "land of the free" and "home of the brave".